# Does react-script-ts support create-react-app and CSS/SCSS Modules?

Tags: create-react-app, css-modules, react-css-modules

Now that create-react-app has released v2, I want to create a new React App using Typescript and SCSSModules or CSSModules?

Am wondering if anyone managed to make this work? I am getting a `Cannot find module ./Styles.module.scss` when I `import styles from "./Styles.module.scss";`

Any thoughts/help with this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is not yet supported by react-script-ts released versions, but you can use it by using the 4.0.8 version of react-scripts-ts.

Please see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4837